# Sculpting issues - doesn't smoothen

Tags: sculpting, subdivision-surface, sculpt

I have a couple of issues in blender.

1. Sculpting

When I sculpt, it isn't smoothened at all. E.g. in the following images, I tried to draw but it just ends up emphasizing all the edges/faces of the model. When I try to add a subdivision modifier it ends up severely messing up the model.

before draw tool:
[image]
after draw tool:
[image]
if I add subdivision modifier:
[image]

Can someone please help me with these issues. Thank you so much for your time.

(EDIT 1: after remesh > draw tool to add volume > smoothen)
you can tell that the edges of the faces are very prominent when I try to smoothen them... If I smoothen any further the model breaks apart.)
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots hey I can't upload the file, the upload progress bar doesn't move at all. are there any other platforms i could upload it on?

Comment: read the instructions, you need to enter this page URL, then share the link it will generate

Comment: my bad. here you go https://blend-exchange.com/b/WKWQ3Nz6/

Comment: If you're talking about the torso I'm not sure what's happening, the mesh seems ok and I don't know how you end up with picture 2

Comment: all I did was use the draw tool in sculpt mode, trying to create volume.. Don't know how it got like that. Any possible reason?

Comment: Hey, i've updated my original post with 3 images to show what happens when i try to smoothen anything (but in this case, the torso). The faces all become prominent after i try to smoothen them. Any possible fix? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Some parts of the model like the arms and legs have flipped faces. Others lack geometry. For example, if you add a cylinder and apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier the mesh has still different density in parts. You can check this with the [wireframe overlay](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html). I would join all parts (Ctrl+J), apply all modifiers, and remesh the model in sculpt mode (key R (or Shift+R in older versions) to choose the voxel size, Ctrl+R to remesh. This way, you get a mesh with even density that is merged and hasn't flipped normals.

Comment: When you say that you smoothen, do you mean Shift left click? If I try on the torso it works fine. Maybe show a video of the problem when you sculpt? Also as Blunder says you need to recalculate the faces of some other parts